# Can connect to MSSQL 11 with SQL Auth, but can't connect with the same credentials to "import and export" wizard

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I'm connecting to a MSSql 11.0.2100 server named "server" with a user named "user" via SQL auth.

When I try the exact same credentials in the "import and export" wizard, the connection fails with: `Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server server connection (Microsoft Sql Server Native Client 11.0)`

What am I missing? thanks!